# react-pose delay the pose group height transition until after children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, popmotion, react-pose

```
const Item = posed.div({
  enter: {x: 0, opacity: 1},
  exit: {x: 1000, opacity: 0}
});

<PoseGroup>
  <Item key={whatever}></Item>
</PoseGroup>
```

Currently when I remove an item from the list, the pose group div gets shorter and the item slides out at the same time. How do I tell the pose group to wait until item has finished animating before updating the height of the pose group? To delay an Item, you add `delay` to the config, but how do I delay a pose group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that the `PoseGroup` sets each exiting element to `position: absolute` which takes it out of the natural flow of elements. This is why the other elements jump up immediately.

`PoseGroup` provided a prop to turn off this feature called `flipMove`.

```
<PoseGroup flipMove={false}>
```

> When an element exits, Pose takes it out of the layout and applies
>   position: absolute so it can detect the new position of surrounding
>   elements and animate via FLIP.
>
> While it attempts to figure out the correct matching transform-origin
>   there are times when this fails. Setting flipMove={false} will prevent
>   these issues.

Source: https://popmotion.io/pose/api/posegroup/

Here's a working example of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-beaver-3o6m3

Comment: Is there any way to gently move the other elements up (slowly move the remain children up)?